# Presto on (Py)Spark - setup

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, presto

Through my job as a data engineer most of my data logic is through:

1. presto queries (small - medium data sets and calculation, easiest for working with analysts)
2. Spark (the big guns, when the calculations are pretty heavy), mostly in python environment.

Although there are several scenarios I prefer to work smarter with presto (data sketch functions) then utilize spark.

The scenario I'm looking for is to integrate presto framework with pyspark. and Im failing to setup it correctly in the session level.
tried to convert the spark-submit example in presto docs to a pyspark session builder without any luck.

/spark/bin/spark-submit 
--master spark://spark-master:7077 
--executor-cores 4 
--conf spark.task.cpus=4 
--class com.facebook.presto.spark.launcher.PrestoSparkLauncher 
presto-spark-launcher-0.271.jar 
--package presto-spark-package-0.271.tar.gz 
--config /presto/etc/config.properties 
--catalogs /presto/etc/catalogs 
--catalog hive 
--schema default 
--file query.sql

loaded the jsons successfully:
[config snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8098P.png)

but when trying to run spark.sql with presto syntax I still fail.
What am I missing?

I was following this documentation:
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/spark.html

This official GIT:
https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/13856

And tried to get more data across the web (there isn't much)
https://medium.com/@ravishankar.nair/the-ultimate-duo-in-distributed-computing-prestodb-running-on-spark-b63d0e567eeb

Comment: Just out of curiosity why not just load the content directly from within the files and use spark entirely? of course, you can specify the hive catalog and still work directly without using the PrestoSparkLauncher.
perform your calculations meaning ETL over the files, and save the output?

Comment: Well given enough hardware and config tuning spark will eventually deliver on its own.

A lot of my processes includes vast percentiles calculations. presto handles it mostly better in my experience (think of data sketching - calculating full week with 7 days parallel independent processes and then doing an efficient union) .

At the end my presto cluster have by design limits, integrate it with the spark architecture I will benefit in very efficient logic.